# django tests cannot modify session

Tags: django, django-testing, django-sessions

In my test I have the following code.

```py
import uuid

from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase


class ExampleTestCase(APITestCase):
    def test_set_session(self):
        machine_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        session = self.client.session
        session['machine_id'] = machine_id
        session.save()
        response = self.client.delete(reverse('current-user'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

And then in my view, I do this.

```py
def current_user(request):
    print(request.session.get('machine_id'))
```

However the session key is missing apparently.
Why is this happening? Is this a bug in django?

**EDIT**
I've managed to simplify the case.
In this snippet below,

```py
        machine_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        session = self.client.session
        session['machine_id'] = machine_id
        session.save()

        print(self.client.session.keys())
        # here session.keys() is empty.
```

the keys are empty as soon as they are set.

Comment: take a look at [this part of documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.session). As it reads **because a new SessionStore is created every time this property is accessed**, I suspect that you access `self.client.session` in other methods of the test case.

Comment: As far as I know, I only modify the session via a middleware. But u dont modify it in my test case.

Comment: The middleware inserts another key into the session. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: where `self.client` comes from?

Comment: please check my edits! The client attribute comes from the rest_framework Test Case. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was because my backend was `django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies`. Changing it to the default backend (`django.contrib.sessions.backends.db`) solved it.